# Binomial distribution with fractional number of successes

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I have a stochastic variable with binomial distribution $T\sim B(n,\frac{1}{4})$

I need to estimate $n : P(0.30 < \frac{T}{n} < 0.70) > 0.95$

I have tried to resolve this problem with

$P(0.30 < \frac{T}{n} < 0.70) = P(T <0.70n) - P(T < 0.30n)$

but I don't know how can I proceed because I don't know the $\operatorname{Img}(T)$

Answer (score 1):

No such $n$ exists.  For sufficiently "large" $n$, we can use a normal approximation to the binomial and show that the function $$R(n) = \Phi\left(\frac{9\sqrt{n}}{5\sqrt{3}}\right) - \Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{5\sqrt{3}}\right)$$ where $\Phi(z) = \Pr[Z \le z]$ is the standard normal CDF, has derivative $$r(n) = \frac{e^{-27n/50}(9-e^{8n/15})}{10\sqrt{6\pi n}}$$ with critical point at $n = \frac{15}{4} \log 3 \approx 4.1198$.  This is a global maximum on $n > 0$, but $$R(4.1198) \approx 0.389891 < 0.95,$$ with very little hope of the exact binomial probability getting that large.  But we make a table anyway:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
n & \lceil 0.3n \rceil & \lfloor 0.7n \rfloor & \Pr[0.3n < T < 0.7n] \\
\hline
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & 1 & 1 & \frac{3}{8} \\
 3 & 1 & 2 & \frac{9}{16} \\
 4 & 2 & 2 & \frac{27}{128} \\
 5 & 2 & 3 & \frac{45}{128} \\
 6 & 2 & 4 & \frac{945}{2048} \\
 7 & 3 & 4 & \frac{945}{4096} \\
 8 & 3 & 5 & \frac{10395}{32768} \\
\end{array}$$

The maximum probability occurs at $n = 3$, but $9/16 < 0.95$.

Comment: +1 though I would prefer the final column of that table to be as decimal fractions

Comment: Why you use a normal approximation and not the Poisson approximation with parameter $np = \frac{n}{4}$?

Comment: @Simone It doesn’t matter.  Either approximation will show that the desired probability is not attainable.